# Set query param value to default on type mismatch in spring boot rest api

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi-generator

We have a rest api built with spring boot and the openapi code generator. Let's assume there is a path `/user` in our api spec:

```
...
"paths": {
    "/user": {
        "get": {
            "parameters": [{
                "name": "id",
                "in": "query",
                "required": false,
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int64"
            }],
            "responses": { ... }
        },
    }
    // more paths
}
...
```

A call to this path could then be: `/user?id=1234`.

The code generator creates an interface MyControllerApi:

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "some date")
@Api(value="user")
public interface MyControllerApi {
    @ApiOperation(value="", nickname="userGet", response = User.class, /* ... */)
    @ApiResponse(/* ... */)
    @GetMapping(value="/user", produces = { "application/json" })
    ResponseEntity<User> userGet(@ApiParam(value = "id") @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long id);
}
```

The controller then looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyController implements MyControllerApi
{
    @Autowired
    UserService service;
    
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<User> userGet(@RequestParam(value = "id") Long id) {
        return service.get(id);
    }
}
```

If `/user?id=<value>` is requested, spring boot automatically checks if the type of the passed parameter value `<value>` matches the required type. If not `BAD_REQUEST` is returned:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-10-19T17:20:48.393+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/user"
}
```

We are now in a situation in which we want to pass `null` to each parameter of `userGet` that would cause a type mismatch. To be more clear: if `/user?id=abcd` is requested, `userGet` should be called with `id` set to null, so that we can return some default user. Is there a way to achieve this?

Of course there are a lot more paths and parameters and this behavior should apply for every query parameter of type `Long` or `Boolean`.

This example may not make much sense, but it is also just an example.

Thanks in advance

### What I tried myself in the meantime

#### 1. Setting the spring-boot `useOptional` option ...

... to `true` in the pom.xml (see [here](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/)).

This has the affect that the query parameters in the controllers method are of type `Optional<?>`. In my example above this would lead to:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<User> userGet(Optional<Long> id) {
    Long id_val = id.isPresent() ? id.get() : null;
    return service.get(id_val);
}
```

But this did not work either and spring boot also creates a `BAD_REQUEST` response on parameter type mismatches.

#### 2. Using a request interceptor

A request interceptor is a kind of middleware and can be created by implementing `HandlerInterceptor` and enables you to process the request before it is passed to the controller.

My interceptor looks like this:

```
public class CustomRequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
    {
        HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        MethodParameter[] handlerParams = method.getMethodParameters();

        while (request.getParameterNames().hasMoreElements())
        {
            // the param name of the query
            String paramName = request.getParameterNames().nextElement();
             the param value
            String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);
            MethodParameter methodParam = null;

            for (MethodParameter mp : handlerParams)
            {
                // We can access annotations here ...
                Annotation anno = mp.getParameterAnnotation(RequestParam.class);
                if(anno != null)
                {
                    RequestParam rp = (RequestParam) anno;

                    // ... and am able to get the param name in the controller
                    // Check if we found the param
                    String requestParamName = rp.value();
                    if (requestParamName.toLowerCase().equals(paramName.toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        // and now?
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (methodParam != null)
            {
                Type type = methodParam.getGenericParameterType();
            }
        }

        return HandlerInterceptor.super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```

So far so good, but the RequestParam-Object does not hold any informations about the parameter type, nor about the index of that param in the methods param list. And the MethodParameter does not hold the name of the parameter (because its a compiled class I think).

What I'm wondering is how spring boot itself maps the query parameters to the ones in the controllers methods..... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I found a solution by using a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`:

```
public class MyCustomResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Object resolveArgument(
        MethodParameter methodParam,
        @Nullable ModelAndViewContainer mvContainer,
        NativeWebRequest request,
        @Nullable WebDataBinderFactory binderFac
    ) throws Exception {
        String paramValue = request.getParameter(methodParam.getParameterName());
        if (paramValue == null)
            return null;

        if (methodParam.getParameterType().equals(Long.class)) {
            try {
                // Set param value to the parsed one, if it can be parsed
                return Long.parseLong(paramValue);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Set param value to null otherwise
                return null;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(Long.class));
    }
}
```

The method `supportsParameter()` gives you the opportunity to decide whether or not the passed parameter will be processed in `resolveArgument`.

`resolveArgument` then gets the parameter as `MethodParameter`. Unlike in the `HandlerInterceptor` the `MethodParameter` now contains the parameter name and type.

Using this approach `id` will have the following values:

```
id = 1     on /user?id=1
id = null  on /user?id=abc
```

Now I'am able to handle falsy parameter values in the controller directly.

###### Remarks

If you use a parameter of type `Boolean` the param value will not be null but "false" for every parameter value except `true`. Only if "true" is passed in the request `resolveArgument` will parse it to `true` and `getUser` will receive `true`.